# traceback not full when passing to next fucntion

Tags: python, exception, traceback

Basically I have something like this:

```
import traceback
def function1():
    try:
        temp = None
        temp = int(temp)
    except:
        pass
```

Which obviously rises error (due to casting `NoneType` to `int`), then there is a second method that is called only if previous one had error:

```
def function2():
    # do something
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Though it doesn't print full traceback as it would do if invoked in the `except` clause, it just says:

```
NoneType: None
```

Where does this change come from? And is there any way to still print a full stack trace?

Comment: Where and how do you call function2() ?

Answer (score 1):

If you call like this, the error context, the traceback does not longer exists as you went away from it

```
function1()
function2()
```

You need to call `function2` from the `except` block, to keep track of the traceback

```py
import traceback

def function1():
    try:
        temp = None
        temp = int(temp)
    except:
        function2()

def function2():
    traceback.print_exc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function1()
```

Giving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\test_4.py", line 7, in function1
    temp = int(temp)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```